# Adding to attributes based on shared line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

using 2.18.16 QGIS
Trying to attribute shared poly lines.
for example  would like to calc the adjoining polygon name to a attribute filed Called Adjoin_Po.

[image]

so for P01 it would be 'P02,P08'
for P10 it would be 'P03,P11,P17,P09'

[image]

for the above image I am looking to query out 4,8,6,2.  The green ones and not the red ones 1,7,9,3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a `Virtual Layer`.

(1) Go to `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer`

(2) Import your grid layer (assumed `Grid` in the following example).

(3) Give syntax as below: (if your unique id field is not `fid`, please change `.fid` to your id field).

```
SELECT t1.fid AS id1, t2.fid AS id2
FROM Grid AS t1, Grid AS t2
WHERE t1.fid != t2.fid
AND st_length(st_intersection(t1.geometry, t2.geometry)) > 0
```

[image]

This will create a table above. To be honest I prefer this table.

(4) As required, another syntax to create `Adjoin_Po` field to store all adjacent polygons. You will notice the middle part (inside `FROM( )`) is exactly same as the first syntax.

```
SELECT t0.id1 AS id, Group_Concat(t0.id2, ',') AS Adjoin_Po
FROM(
  SELECT t1.fid AS id1, t2.fid AS id2
  FROM Grid AS t1, Grid AS t2
  WHERE t1.fid != t2.fid
  AND st_length(st_intersection(t1.geometry, t2.geometry)) > 0
) AS t0
GROUP BY  t0.id1
```

[image]

Comment: This worked well , almost too well..  this is garbing all 8 of the surrounding polygons  only need it to grab the ones that share a line with each of the "Grids"  think of it as I need the ones touching  top, bottom, left, right.  and NOT include the ones at the corners. I have up dated the original post with a image of a Grid.  Green ones are the ones i am trying to look at. Again thank you so mush for the help!

Comment: @user12577 Thanks for update and adding schematic description. I understand it more clearly. Please see updated syntax and pictures. HTH.

Comment: so i have come back to this to try it again and i get this message: "Layer is not valid: The layer ?layer=ogr:%2Fhome%2Fzac%2FStaking%2FPatten%2FClaims%2FGrid.shp:Grid:UTF-8&query=SELECT%20t0.id1%20AS%20id,%20Group_Concat(t0.id2,%20',')%20AS%20Adjoin_Po%0AFROM(%0A%20%20SELECT%20t1.fid%20AS%20id1,%20t2.fid%20AS%20id2%0A%20%20FROM%20Grid%20AS%20t1,%20Grid%20AS%20t2%0A%20%20WHERE%20t1.fid%20!%3D%20t2.fid%0A%20%20AND%20st_length(st_intersection(t1.geometry,%20t2.geometry))%20%3E%200%0A)%20AS%20t0%0AGROUP%20BY%20%20t0.id1%20 is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map"      thoughts?

Comment: Hi @user12577 Is the data you are working on the same as before?

Comment: @user12577 - did this solution work for you at any stage? Helpful (and rewarding!) to click the 'accept' check mark when answers are successful!

Comment: this is my process. if you have a sex @user12577 could you take a look at it?  I have a layer in Qgis named "Grid" with one attribute to it called "fid"  I add it to a blank project and add a virtual layer, import "Grid" and paste in the lower section of code above.  test it then hit OK, the virtual layer is then added into the project but not data is in the layer.  Thoughts