# Update to Bonn 3.2 QGIS seems to have had a effect on some of my code

Tags: qgis, update

I asked a question here:[Adding to attributes based on shared line in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282957/adding-to-attributes-based-on-shared-line-in-qgis) but it seems that in Bonn 3.2 QGIS this does not work.  Any ideas what has changed for it not to work, other snippets of code seems not to work as well since the update?  For example, this is the code from the post above:

```
SELECT t0.id1 AS id, Group_Concat(t0.id2, ',') AS Adjoin_Po
FROM(
  SELECT t1.fid AS id1, t2.fid AS id2
  FROM Grid AS t1, Grid AS t2
  WHERE t1.fid != t2.fid
  AND st_length(st_intersection(t1.geometry, t2.geometry)) > 0
) AS t0
GROUP BY  t0.id1
```

Comment: Will you test it using the latest QGIS 3.2.2 ?

Comment: I have updated to 3.2.2 and still not working.. also WFS layers seem to be freezing up and crashing the projext

Comment: I have seen some issues surrounding Virtual Layer lately, not only with QGIS3.2 but also QGIS2.18.19-21. Thought this has been fixed by now, but there might be remaining bug. Please use older versions for a while.